# Is it possible to add animation to Ajax Modal Popup Extender in javascript?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-8, modalpopupextender

I have an ajax modal popup that animates the popup panel in.

Everything works fine in Firefox et al, but there are a couple of issues in IE8.

1) The text looks grainy (as per when you use a filter with text).
2) Hover state on buttons does not work.

I'm trying to find a solution, but struggling to come up with an answer. Maybe one solution is to try and call animation from javascript rather than place it in the aspx page.

Any ideas?